# How to make Alt+Shift act like AltGr with xmodmap?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, arch-linux, xmodmap

I just swapped from Windows and I was used to using Alt+Shift to type special characters such as `|@#~½¬`from the number row, but it only works with Alt Gr on Ubuntu. It's not in the settings either so I figured xmodmap is the way to go. But the only way to make it work I've found is by remapping every single special character, like `keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus semicolon colon`.

Is there any way of copying Alt Gr to Alt+Shift?

Comment: There's quite a few questions about remapping altgr here. These might be a good place to continue your research while waiting for an answer: https://superuser.com/search?q=altgr

Comment: As I've said, these only suggest adding every single special character to the list. The closest I saw was `xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Alt_R"`, which only adds it to the left alt instead of to left alt + shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion after hours of trying that it is not possible with `Autokey`, `xmodmap` or `setxkbmap` to copy AltGr to Alt_L and Shift_L.

- **Autokey** doesn't allow a shortcut like Alt+Shift, since it also needs another character. Alt, Shift, Control... only count as combinations with other keys and they won't work by themselves
- **xmodmap** should have worked with `xmodmap -e "keysym Meta_L = ISO_Level3_Shift"` but it only assigns the function to Alt_L, Shift_L does something similar, typing different special characters. Besides, when this is activated, these keys will only work for that purpose (You can't do Alt+Tab etc)
- **setxkbmap** should have worked too with `setxkbmap -option Meta_L:ISO_Level3_Shift` but it apparently does nothing. When tested with `xev` it does change the input key but it's something different from ISO_Level3_Shift